# Values from multiple dataframe columns into one vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that has many cols and say 100 rows.

How do I take all the level values from the columns with names "alpha", "gamma" and "zeta" and store the 300 of them in a single vector?

Comment: `unlist(df[c("the","cols","you","want")], use.names = FALSE)`?

Comment: Yep almost there ... now that returns me a single vector with the levels indexes as values, what happened to the "names" of the levels? That is turning the factors back into characters?

Comment: You need to clarify whether you want values as levels (not what you question states) or just a vector of levels (which is what you were asking).

Comment: Why don't you make a tiny 3x5 `data.frame` that demonstrates your input and a `vector` that shows your desired output. When I use `unlist` as demonstrated above, the `factors` remained as `factors` *unless* one of the columns was a `character` column.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found that converting to a matrix first makes getting to levels a bit easier.

```
as.vector(as.matrix(df[,c("alpha", "gamma", "zeta")]))
```

Of course, you could have just done `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you read the data in initially.

Comment: Swift and elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You have an accepted answer, but here's what I think is happening: You have a combination of `factor` and `character` columns. In that case, `unlist` doesn't work directly, but if they were all `factor` or if they were all `character`, there would be no problem:

Some sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:3], B = LETTERS[4:6], C = LETTERS[7:9],
                   D = LETTERS[10:12], E = LETTERS[13:15])
df <- mydf
df$E <- as.character(df$E)
colsOfInterest <- c("A", "B", "E")
```

#### Case 1, all columns are factors

```
unlist(mydf[colsOfInterest], use.names = FALSE)
# [1] A B C D E F M N O
# Levels: A B C D E F M N O
```

#### Case 2, column E = characters, other columns factors

```
unlist(df[colsOfInterest], use.names = FALSE)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "3" "M" "N" "O"

unlist(lapply(df[colsOfInterest], as.character), use.names = FALSE)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "M" "N" "O"
```

---

For a problem at the scale described here, the benchmarks show that converting to character first and using `unlist` is actually the fastest approach if you don't care for retaining factors. Note that the result of `fun1()` won't be correct if some columns are factors and some are characters. Here's a benchmark on a 100 row `data.frame`:

```
library(microbenchmark)    
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3())
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr      min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#  fun1()  572.606  587.3595  595.4845  606.175 3439.055   100
#  fun2()  327.570  334.6265  341.2550  350.449 3443.758   100
#  fun3() 1037.020 1055.6215 1064.1745 1086.197 3929.981   100
```

Of course, here we're talking microseconds, but the results scale too.

For reference, here's what was used for benchmarking. Change "`nRow`" and "`nCol`" if you want to test on a different sized `data.frame` extracting different numbers of columns.

```
nRow <- 100
nCol <- 30
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS, nRow*nCol, replace = TRUE), nrow = nRow))
colsOfInterest <- sample(nCol, sample(nCol*.7, 1))
length(colsOfInterest)
# [1] 17

library(microbenchmark)    
fun1 <- function() unlist(mydf[colsOfInterest], use.names = FALSE)
fun2 <- function() unlist(lapply(mydf[colsOfInterest], as.character), use.names = FALSE)
fun3 <- function() as.vector(as.matrix(mydf[colsOfInterest]))
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3())
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine all columns of a data.frame into a single vector like so:

```r
unname(unlist(your_data_frame))
```

#### Minimal reproducible example

This example takes the first 3 rows of the built-in data.frame `mpg` and combines all its columns into a single vector:

```r
df <- head(mpg, 3)
df
#  manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
# 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
# 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
# 3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact


unname(unlist(df))
#  [1] "audi"       "audi"       "audi"       "a4"        
#  [5] "a4"         "a4"         "1.8"        "1.8"       
#  [9] "2"          "1999"       "1999"       "2008"      
# [13] "4"          "4"          "4"          "auto(l5)"  
# [17] "manual(m5)" "manual(m6)" "f"          "f"         
# [21] "f"          "18"         "21"         "20"        
# [25] "29"         "29"         "31"         "p"         
# [29] "p"          "p"          "compact"    "compact"   
# [33] "compact"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 vec <- unlist(lapply( df[ , 
                        names(df) %in% c("alpha","gamma", "zeta") ],
                levels) )[1:300]
```

That would give the unique levels. If you want the first 300 values in those columns, do this:

```
 vec <- unlist(lapply( df[ , 
                        names(df) %in% c("alpha","gamma", "zeta") ],
                as.character) )[1:300]
```